# Convert json LocalDate to LocalDateTime using Spring boot

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I have a json like below:

```
{
 "transactiedatum": [
  2021,
  5,
  1
 ]
 //... other field
}
```

How I will convert this to LocalDateTime with the beginning of date.

```
public class MyDto{
    @JsonProperty("transactiedatum")
    // Which annotation should use here to convert LocalDate to LocalDateTime?
    private LocalDateTime verstuurdOp;
}
```

Comment: `transactiedatum` does not  seem to be `LocalDate`, it is not even a valid Json... I think  you will need to implement your own parser for this...

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado, It works If I use LocalDate instead of LocalDateTime.

Comment: What time values would you want to assign? Anyway, you could of course just create a `LocalDateTime` getter which just enriches the existing date field.

Comment: @daniu, at Start Of Day HH:mm= 00:00

Comment: If you already got your `LocalDate`, just do `date.atStartOfDay()` and it will put midnight on the time part. [Reference](https://beginnersbook.com/2017/10/java-convert-localdate-to-localdatetime/)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue using custom deserialisation.

```
@JsonProperty("transactiedatum")
@JsonDeserialize(using = JsonDateTimeDeserializer.class)
private LocalDateTime verstuurdOp;
```

And

```
public class JsonDateTimeDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<LocalDateTime> {
    @Override
    public LocalDateTime deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectCodec oc = jp.getCodec();
        ArrayNode node = (ArrayNode) oc.readTree(jp);
        LocalDate datum = LocalDate.of(node.get(0).asInt(), node.get(1).asInt(), node.get(2).asInt());
        return datum.atStartOfDay();
    }
}
```